# Labels and Imageviews oddly behaves in custom cell in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom cell that has labels and imageviews. The labels and imageviews are displayed based on the condition. My custom cell oddly behaves when uitableview is scrolled. There is an instance where when i scroll the one label and imageview the label and imageviews are displayed but when i scroll back to the imageviews and label one label and imageview will disappear, sometimes it overlaps another imageview and label. Here's what I tried so far:

```
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"JobDetailCell";
MTJobDetailCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[MTJobDetailCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
```

I still get the same result. I read another solution and moved my calculations in my customcell.m file. This is in the **layoutSubviews** method.

```
NSInteger tempCount = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"BenefitsCounter"];
NSDictionary *tempDictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"IncentivesAndBenefits"]];
//TEST
NSLog(@"TEMP INT:%ld", (long)tempCount);
NSLog(@"TEMP ARRAY:%@", tempDictionary);

BOOL iFood = tempDictionary[@"food"][@"1"];
NSString* iFoodDescription = tempDictionary[@"food"][@"1"];
BOOL iCommission = tempDictionary[@"commission"][@"1"];
NSString* iCommissionDescription = tempDictionary[@"commission"][@"1"];
BOOL iUniform = tempDictionary[@"uniform"][@"1"];
NSString* iUniformDescription = tempDictionary[@"uniform"][@"1"];
BOOL iTransport = tempDictionary[@"transport"][@"1"];
NSString* iTransportDescription = tempDictionary[@"transport"][@"1"];
BOOL iExtras = tempDictionary[@"extras"][@"1"];
NSString* iExtrasDescription = tempDictionary[@"extras"][@"1"];

//MARK: POSITION labels and imageviews
int img_x = kImgStart_x;
int img_w = kImgStart_w;
int img_h = kImgStart_h;

//result value positions
int lbl_x = kLblStart_x;
int lbl_y = kLblStart_y;
int lbl_w = kLblStart_w;

if(tempCount == 1)
{
    if(iCommission)
    {
        //decrement
        tempCount--;
        CGSize expectedSize =[self GetTextHightForLable:iCommissionDescription];

        self.imgCommissionIncentive.frame = CGRectMake(img_x, lbl_y, img_w, img_h);
        self.imgCommissionIncentive.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-commission.png"];
        self.lblCommissionIncentive.frame = CGRectMake(lbl_x, lbl_y, lbl_w, expectedSize.height+10);
    }

    if(iExtras)
    {
        //decrement
        tempCount--;
        CGSize expectedSize =[self GetTextHightForLable:iExtrasDescription];

        self.imgExtrasIncentive.frame = CGRectMake(img_x, lbl_y, img_w, img_h);
        self.imgExtrasIncentive.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-extras.png"];
        self.lblExtrasIncentive.frame = CGRectMake(lbl_x, lbl_y, lbl_w, expectedSize.height+10);
    }

    if(iFood)
    {
        //decrement
        tempCount--;
        CGSize expectedSize =[self GetTextHightForLable:iFoodDescription];

        self.imgFoodIncentive.frame = CGRectMake(img_x, lbl_y, img_w, img_h);
        self.imgFoodIncentive.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-food.png"];
        self.lblFoodIncentive.frame = CGRectMake(lbl_x, lbl_y, lbl_w, expectedSize.height+10);
    }

    if(iTransport)
    {
        //decrement
        tempCount--;
        CGSize expectedSize =[self GetTextHightForLable:iTransportDescription];

        self.imgTransportIncentive.frame = CGRectMake(img_x, lbl_y, img_w, img_h);
        self.imgTransportIncentive.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-transport.png"];
        self.lblTransportIncentive.frame = CGRectMake(lbl_x, lbl_y, lbl_w, expectedSize.height+10);
    }

    if(iUniform)
    {
        //decrement
        tempCount--;
        CGSize expectedSize =[self GetTextHightForLable:iUniformDescription];

        self.imgUniformIncentive.frame = CGRectMake(img_x, lbl_y, img_w, img_h);
        self.imgUniformIncentive.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-uniform2.png"];
        self.lblUniformIncentive.frame = CGRectMake(lbl_x, lbl_y, lbl_w, expectedSize.height+10);
    }
}
else if (tempCount > 1)
{
    if(iCommission)
    {
        //decrement
        tempCount--;
        CGSize expectedSize =[self GetTextHightForLable:iCommissionDescription];

        self.imgCommissionIncentive.frame = CGRectMake(img_x, lbl_y, img_w, img_h);
        self.imgCommissionIncentive.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-commission.png"];
        self.imgCommissionIncentive.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        self.lblCommissionIncentive.frame = CGRectMake(lbl_x, lbl_y, lbl_w, expectedSize.height+10);

        lbl_y += kResult_Y_incr;
    }

    if(iExtras)
    {
        //decrement
        tempCount--;
        CGSize expectedSize =[self GetTextHightForLable:iExtrasDescription];

        self.imgExtrasIncentive.frame = CGRectMake(img_x, lbl_y, img_w, img_h);
        self.imgExtrasIncentive.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-extras.png"];
        self.imgExtrasIncentive.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        self.lblExtrasIncentive.frame = CGRectMake(lbl_x, lbl_y, lbl_w, expectedSize.height+10);

        lbl_y += kResult_Y_incr;
    }

    if(iFood)
    {
        //decrement
        tempCount--;
        CGSize expectedSize =[self GetTextHightForLable:iFoodDescription];

        self.imgFoodIncentive.frame = CGRectMake(img_x, lbl_y, img_w, img_h);
        self.imgFoodIncentive.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-food.png"];
        self.imgFoodIncentive.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        self.lblFoodIncentive.frame = CGRectMake(lbl_x, lbl_y, lbl_w, expectedSize.height+10);

        lbl_y += kResult_Y_incr;
    }

    if(iTransport)
    {
        //decrement
        tempCount--;
        CGSize expectedSize =[self GetTextHightForLable:iTransportDescription];

        self.imgTransportIncentive.frame = CGRectMake(img_x, lbl_y, img_w, img_h);
        self.imgTransportIncentive.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-transport.png"];
        self.imgTransportIncentive.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        self.lblTransportIncentive.frame = CGRectMake(lbl_x, lbl_y, lbl_w, expectedSize.height+10);

        lbl_y += kResult_Y_incr;
    }

    if(iUniform)
    {
        //decrement
        tempCount--;
        CGSize expectedSize =[self GetTextHightForLable:iUniformDescription];

        self.imgUniformIncentive.frame = CGRectMake(img_x, lbl_y, img_w, img_h);
        self.imgUniformIncentive.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-uniform2.png"];
        self.imgUniformIncentive.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        self.lblUniformIncentive.frame = CGRectMake(lbl_x, lbl_y, lbl_w, expectedSize.height+10);

        lbl_y += kResult_Y_incr;
    }
}
```

This is my code for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    NSString *strIncentives = [[self.jobDetailDict objectForKey:@"sub_slots"] objectForKey:@"incentives_and_benefits"];
    if(![strIncentives length] == 0)
    {
        NSData *jsonData = [strIncentives dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSError *error;
        iBenefitsCounter = 0;

        incentives = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                      error:&error];

        //TEST
        //NSLog(@"INCETIVES DICT: %@", incentives);

        //BOOL iCommission = incentives[@"commission"][@"1"];
        NSString *iCommissionDescription = incentives[@"commission"][@"1"];
        if([iCommissionDescription isEqualToString:@""] || incentives[@"commission"][@"0"])
        {
            [cell.imgCommissionIncentive setHidden:true];
            [cell.lblCommissionIncentive setHidden:true];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.imgCommissionIncentive setHidden:false];
            cell.imgCommissionIncentive.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-commission.png"];

            [cell.lblCommissionIncentive setHidden:false];
            [cell.lblCommissionIncentive setText:iCommissionDescription];
            cell.lblCommissionIncentive.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Light" size:13.0f];
            iBenefitsCounter++;
        }

        //BOOL iExtras = incentives[@"extras"][@"1"];
        NSString *iExtrasDescription = incentives[@"extras"][@"1"];
        if([iExtrasDescription isEqualToString:@""] || incentives[@"extras"][@"0"])
        {
            [cell.imgExtrasIncentive setHidden:true];
            [cell.lblExtrasIncentive setHidden:true];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.imgExtrasIncentive setHidden:false];
            cell.imgExtrasIncentive.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-extras.png"];

            [cell.lblExtrasIncentive setHidden:false];
            [cell.lblExtrasIncentive setText:iExtrasDescription];
            cell.lblExtrasIncentive.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Light" size:13.0f];
            iBenefitsCounter++;
        }

        //BOOL iFood = incentives[@"food"][@"1"];
        NSString *iFoodDescription = incentives[@"food"][@"1"];
        if([iFoodDescription isEqualToString:@""] || incentives[@"food"][@"0"])
        {
            [cell.imgFoodIncentive setHidden:true];
            [cell.lblFoodIncentive setHidden:true];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.imgFoodIncentive setHidden:false];
            cell.imgFoodIncentive.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-food.png"];

            [cell.lblFoodIncentive setHidden:false];
            [cell.lblFoodIncentive setText:iFoodDescription];
            cell.lblFoodIncentive.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Light" size:13.0f];
            iBenefitsCounter++;
        }

        //BOOL iTransport = incentives[@"transport"][@"1"];
        NSString *iTransportDescription = incentives[@"transport"][@"1"];
        if([iTransportDescription isEqualToString:@""] || incentives[@"transport"][@"0"])
        {
            [cell.imgUniformIncentive setHidden:true];
            [cell.lblUniformIncentive setHidden:true];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.imgTransportIncentive setHidden:false];
            cell.imgTransportIncentive.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-transport.png"];

            [cell.lblUniformIncentive setHidden:false];
            [cell.lblTransportIncentive setText:iTransportDescription];
            cell.lblUniformIncentive.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Light" size:13.0f];
            iBenefitsCounter++;
        }

        //BOOL iUniform = incentives[@"uniform"][@"1"];
        NSString *iUniformDescription = incentives[@"uniform"][@"1"];
        if([iUniformDescription isEqualToString:@""] || incentives[@"uniform"][@"0"])
        {
            [cell.imgUniformIncentive setHidden:true];
            [cell.lblUniformIncentive setHidden:true];

        }
        else
        {
            [cell.imgUniformIncentive setHidden:false];
            cell.imgUniformIncentive.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-uniform2.png"];

            [cell.lblUniformIncentive setHidden:false];
            [cell.lblUniformIncentive setText:iUniformDescription];
            cell.lblUniformIncentive.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Light" size:13.0f];
            iBenefitsCounter++;
        }

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:iBenefitsCounter forKey:@"BenefitsCounter"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:incentives] forKey:@"IncentivesAndBenefits"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        return cell;
    }
```

My code works perfectly in iOS 8. Im really confused why it doesn't work in iOS 7. I have been struggling with this since last week.
Can somebody please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try below code  -

Write Below code after

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[MTJobDetailCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

for(UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews){  
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {  
            [view removeFromSuperview];   
        }
    }
```

**AND**

```
cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Add all UIlabel and UIImage as below

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel] ;
```

Comment: hey thanks for your reply..but where should i put [cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel]; I just tried this solution it now doesnt display anything..

Comment: Check your customcell.m where you add self.lblCommissionIncentive or otherwise post full customcell.m  , I will tell you exactly place where need to add.

Comment: the labels and imageviews are not created programatically..here's what i did, I removed for(UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews){  ... } and the labels and imageviews are displayed again..

Comment: Ok then you don't need [cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel];